# AWK in shell script - How to compare and merge TWO files based on a shared key (2 common fields)?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

Could some one please help to compare two files,
i have used the below command but i couldnt succeed on it,

awk -F, 'NR == FNR {a[$1,$2]; next} (($1,$2) in a )' temp1.dat temp2.dat

Here is my need,
need to compare first two fields in the below two dat files and merge the result as expected in file3(first field, second field, 3 field of temp1.dat,  3 field of temp2.dat)

File1:temp1.dat

```
A, AB,100
B,BB,200
C,CC,300
```

File2:temp2.dat

```
A,AB,10
C,CC,30
D,DF, 4
```

File3 :output

```
A, AB,100,10
C,CC,300,30
```

Comment: why not just `diff file1 file2`?

Comment: i need file3 only matching column H2CO3.

Comment: Use the join command.

Comment: For future readers and @AmitNaidu -- the `join` command is insufficient because the criteria state that two columns must match.  Of course `sed` could be used to combine the key columns first, then, after sorting each file on the new combined key column, `join` would be sufficient (and a final `sed` filter could separate the joined columns again).  Perhaps join would be more efficient for larger files, especially if they are already sorted on both columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}($1$2 in a && $3=$3","a[$1$2])' file2 file1`

tested below:

```
> cat file1
A,AB,100
B,BB,200
C,CC,300
> cat file2
A,AB,10
C,CC,30
D,DF,4
> awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}($1$2 in a && $3=$3","a[$1$2])' file2 file1
A,AB,100,10
C,CC,300,30
>
```

- `FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}` is applied for the first file **file2**
- it says untill `FNR==NR` execute teh block of code.
- FNR=line number of the current file
- NR= line number of the total lines of two files.
- so after the above statement an associative array with index as `$1$2` and value as `$3`.
- Now `($1$2 in a && $3=$3","a[$1$2])`
  this executes for `FNR!=NR`.where in it checks for index $1$2 exists as an index in the  array and then teh second condition is changing the 3rd field of file1 to `$3=$3","a[$1$2]`so now `$0` contains the common(`$1$2`) lines which changed 3rd field in them.

similar logic has to be written for four files also.

Comment: sarathi thanks a lot,its working fine for me, can you please expain the logic which you used here,is it possible to apply the same comparison logic to four files.

Comment: This is very non-idiomatic.  `($1$2 in a && $3=$3","a[$1$2])` would be much more clear if written`$1$2 in a { $3=$3","a[$1$2]; print }`

Comment: It is best to use a separator between the fields in the index. Otherwise if the fields vary in length then part of one field may "blur" over into the other which leads to unpredictable results. Typically one would use `SUBSEP` for this..

Comment: Or simply `$1$2 in a { print $3, a[$1$2] }` since OFS is already set. No cleverness or obfuscation required. Change order of data files as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk -F, '{i=$1 SUBSEP $2} NR==FNR{A[i]=$3; next} i in A{print $0,A[i]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: +1 Better answer. Just needs OFS or comma. Reducing references to $ variables like this can also be a performance win.