# What is correct syntax for awk pattern matching

Tags: linux, awk

I am opening the multiple files with `awk` and i testing this command

I am trying this for testing

`awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{print FILENAME} {print FILENAME}' file2.txt file1.txt`

The second block should execute when NR != FNR but for me its executing all the time.

IS this syntax correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a pattern for the second action, it always executes. If you only want it to execute when NR!=FNR, try something like:

```
NR==FNR { printf("NR==FNR, Filename=%s", FILENAME); }
NR!=FNR { printf("NR!=FNR, Filename=%s", FILENAME); }
```

For better or worse, there's no `else` for patterns, so you normally end up specifying each explicitly.

Comment: But i have seen many examples and someone also said that in typical NR ==FNR case the other brace executes for NR !=FNR . like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172682/how-to-use-awk-to-compare-the-two-files-in-shell-script

Comment: @user2024264: I don't see anything closely analogous there.

Comment: When `sarathi` says `Now ($1$2 in a && $3=$3","a[$1$2]) this executes for FNR!=NR` then he executes the other portion in else case

Comment: @user2024264: Sounds to me like you're misunderstanding the commentary in the other question. The fact remains that an action without a pattern will execute for every input line.

Comment: @user2024264 i think what you are missing is the `next;` after the print statement which skips the second portion