# Fastest way of finding differences between two files in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to find the difference between two files and then put only the differences in a third file. I saw different approaches using awk, diff and comm. Are there any more ?

eg.[Compare two files line by line and generate the difference in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file)

eg.[Copy differences between two files in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065827/copy-differences-between-two-files-in-unix)

I need to know which is the fastest way of finding all the differences and listing them in a file for each of the cases below -

```
Case 1 - file2 = file1 + extra text appended.
Case 2 - file2 and file1 are different.
```

Comment: since this depends on your inputs, it is best to time it yourself

Comment: can you please make your cases more specific, and maybe give some sample code of things you've tried?

Comment: For Case 2 there is `cmp` that compare two files byte by byte.

Comment: You already have a number of alternatives. Use the `time` command to find your answer.

Comment: "Differences" is really undefined, and could mean a lot of things. As for your "Are there more?" question: Of course, anyone could write a new program to find differences.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could try..

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
```

or

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2 > file3
```

or

```
diff file1 file2 | grep "<" | sed 's/^<//g'  > file3
```

or

```
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
```

Comment: Using two large text files where one has an extra paragraph of text near the beginning, I timed all four methods.  The grep, diff, and join methods all failed to find the extra paragraph.  The diff methods needs to grep ">" in addition to "<" to work. I'm not familiar with the grep or join methods. The results: comm: 3.661s, grep: 0.035s, diff: 0.051s, join: 3.811s

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Find what is missing in file1 from file2.
Right answer:  comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | tr -d '\t'

Answer (score 16):

Another option:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -u > file3
```

If you want to see just the duplicate entries use "uniq -d" option:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -d > file3
```

Comment: I like this answer the best because it is straightforward, intuitive, and doesn't involve some complex command line options/syntax.

Comment: Note: one distinction is that for a line that is different, this `uniq` solution will print both `file1` and `file2` versions of the line. The `comm` and `greq` will only print the `file2` version.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to include md5-hash-sums or similar do determine whether there are any differences at all. Then, only compare files which have different hashes...

Comment: But is hashing two files faster than comparing two files?

Answer (score 0):

This will work fast:

Case 1 - File2 = File1 + extra text appended.

grep -Fxvf File2.txt File1.txt >> File3.txt

File 1: 80 Lines
File 2: 100 Lines
File 3: 20 Lines